# <?php echo $_product->getPrice(); ?>

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-1.5

I have two magento sites with same admin. Everything is working fine.I have an issue with product price. Both are running on different domains.On one price is displaying finely.but on another it is not.

Comment: can you elaborate on what the issue is?  Are they showing different prices when they shouldnt? are they displaying the same prices when they shouldnt? is there a tax issue?  is there no output at all?  The more info you can share, the easier it will be to help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Magento admin issue and belongs over on magento.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

Do you have issue in the admin or frontend ?
 Can you Please check below code :

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

above to  `<?php echo $_product->getPrice(); ?>`
I am not sure where you got issue..

Comment: Dont know what the issue is? Magento/app/design/frontend/default/your_theme .........In my project theme folder doenot exist.. Is it normal. Or nay issue ?